# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to load class from JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a project that is supposed to parse texts from PDF files.

Having multiple dependencies I have decided to build a combined JAR with all the dependencies and the classes.

However, when I build JAR including dependencies via *Intellij IDEA* even though the JAR file is added properly and I can import the class the program throws `NoClassDefFoundError` (Please refer to the screenshot).

Firstly, I thought the jar wasn't in the classpath. However, even if I add `-cp TessaractPDF.jar` through VM Options the class still get undetected.
I think it is worth to mention that, everything works smoothly if I build JAR without dependencies and add the dependencies manually.

What should I do?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/afifaniks/parsers/TessPDFParser
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.afifaniks.parsers.TessPDFParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
import me.afifaniks.parsers.TessPDFParser;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.classpath"));
        HashMap<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
        
        arguments.put("imageMode", "binary");
        arguments.put("toFile", false);
        arguments.put("tessDataPath", "/home/afif/Desktop/PDFParser/tessdata");

        TessPDFParser pdfParser = new TessPDFParser("hiers15.pdf", arguments);
        String text = (String) pdfParser.convert();
        System.out.println(text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Test.java` located in the jar?

Comment: `Test.java` is not a part of the JAR rather it is a from which I am trying to use a class from the JAR file.

Comment: How are you trying to load the class? Reflection or import?

Comment: import it is. However, I have added the code snippet here. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you compare the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for differences between your manual build & the intellij one ? Some metadatas in it could explain it.